# How to allow X11-forward for a tmux session which is established in an ssh session without X11-forward?

Tags: linux, ssh, tmux, x11-forwarding

Let's consider two situations.

- Firstly, ssh into a Linux server via `ssh user@server` (denote the ssh session as **S1**), then open a tmux session (denoted by **T1**), and then open an R session in it, finally run `plot(1:10)`, no graphics window pops up.
- Instead, ssh into the Linux server via `ssh -X user@server` (denote the ssh session as **S2**), then open a tmux session (denoted by **T2**), and repeat the above plotting command in R, finally the graphics window can pop up.

However, enter the tmux session **T1** from the ssh session **S2**, and re-plot in R, but no graphics window pops up.

I guess there might be some differences related to the display environment variable, such as `DISPLAY`.

```bash
## ssh session S1
$ echo $DISPLAY

## ssh session S2
$ echo $DISPLAY
localhost:11.0
```

In tmux sessions (R software is already opened), regardless enter from ssh session **S1** or **S2**,

```bash
## tmux session (R is opened) T1
> Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")
[1] ""
## tmux session (R is opened) T2
> Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")
[1] "localhost:11.0"
```

Then I try to reset `DISPLAY` for T2 via

```r
> Sys.setenv("DISPLAY" = "localhost:11.0")
> Sys.getenv("DISPLAY")                                                                                                                                                                
[1] "localhost:11.0"
```

and plot, but still no graphics window pops up.

So just updating `DISPLAY` seems not to work, but I am wondering if there are any ways to allow tmux session **S1** to pop up the graphics window.

In other words, how to allow X11-forward for a tmux session that is already established in an ssh session without X11-forward?

Comment: The `$DISPLAY` environment variable is not the thing which makes X11 forwarding work - it is a sign that it is working. See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46748) for more. It seems to me that the way to set up X11 forwarding would be to manually replicate all the steps that occur when you call `ssh -X`, as set out in that answer. In which case why not  just run `ssh -X` in the first place?

Comment: Hi SamR, thanks for your comment. Sometimes I forget to add the -X option, such as session S1 in my question, so just want to know if there are simple ways to update the existing sessions.

Comment: Fair enough. I think it's probably easier to just quit the session and restart it. Having said that, you could probably put everything in that post into a bash script. As long as you remember SIGHUP everything to pick up the changes (as with `cat /var/run/sshd.pid | xargs kill -1` in the example) I guess it will work... if it does post it as an answer!

Comment: Another option is to maintain a `~/.ssh/config` file for that connection (perhaps others) where you can set `ForwardX11 yes`.